# How do you constantly check collision between Box2d bodies?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am using Libgdx box2d and I need to constantly check collision between bodies, unlike on Libgdx where you can do `rectangle.overlaps(rect1)` on box2d you need to implement `ContactListener` which only have `beginContact()` and `endContact()`. I want to detect collision all the time and not just when it starts or end.

Comment: A collision happens all the time between beginContact and endContact!?

Comment: @luk2302 But if you add something on beginContact, for example printing out a string. The string will only be outputted whenever the collision starts and not during the collision.

Comment: If you do not have any logic in place: yes. But if you set a flag like "isColliding" to true you only have to check that flag every game tick and respond accordingly - checking for a collision will be more expensive.

Comment: How? Fixture.getBody().isColliding() == true ?

Comment: @luk2302 "isColliding" or something similar doesn't exist!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to check this every frame. Just set a boolean when contact is made and contact ends.

```
public class MyBody {
    private boolean colliding;

    //...

    public void update()
    {
        if (beginContact()) colliding = true;
        else if (endContact) colliding = false;

        if (colliding)
        {
            System.out.println("I am colliding...");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("I am not colliding...");
        }
    }
}
```